# Sort list into hash table according to specific comparisson criteria in R

Tags: r, dictionary, hashtable, igraph, environment

I am looking for a way, in R, to convert a list into a hash table, grouping elements that are similar according to a specific criteria.

The details are specific to "graph theory", as explained bellow, but I suppose the answer is a general procedure to hash based on some specific criteria.

The list is comprised of "graph" objects (from igraph package).

```
library(igraph)

#Creating the list of graphs
edgeList <- data.frame(
  idA=c(008, 001, 001, 010, 047, 002, 005, 005),
  idB=c(100, 010, 020, 030, 030, 001, 011, 111)  
)
edgeList$idB= edgeList$idB+0.1
g <- graph_from_data_frame(edgeList, directed = TRUE)
g_list <- decompose(g, mode = "weak")

#from the 8 edges we obtain 5 graphs (connected components of the original graph)
```

The similarity criteria is that graphs must be isomorphic:

```
isomorphic(g_list[[1]],g_list[[4]])
```

How can I hash the indexes for the elements in `g_list` into a hash table?

For this toy example the expected result should be:

```
 g_inded_hash
[[1]]
[1] 1 4

[[2]]
[1] 2 5

[[3]]
[1] 3
```

(not necessarily a list, but some data structure that groups graphs (1 and 4) and (2 and 5) which are similar)

In reality, I have 40 millions of (small) graphs that I need to group according to the isomorphisms.

From searching I found the answer must be related to the [hash](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hash/hash.pdf) package or [environment](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html), but could not adapt that into a solution.

EDIT: changed `directed = TRUE` in `graph_from_data_frame()`, above.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `igraph` (so some builtin tool might exist for this task) but, since you mention about something more general, you could (1) make all pairwise comparisons with `combn` (2) build a "dist" object from the previous result and (3) make clusters using this object and builtin R tools. I.e. `split(seq_along(g_list), cutree(hclust(structure(!combn(g_list, 2, function(x) isomorphic(x[[1]], x[[2]])), class = "dist", Size = length(g_list))), h = 0.5))`

Comment: tks. I have ~40million graphs, so pairwise comparisons are out of the question, as that would be O(n^2) (see discussion on the answer bellow). The nice property of a hash table is that each new element (graph) would only be compared only to one element of each group. So as more and more elements get grouped, the number of comparisons remaining decreases fast

Answer (score 2):

Since isomorphism is transitive, we can look at all the pairs of components (i,j), such that i < j, then build a graph where the nodes are the components and the edges are defined by the isomorphic property. The hash table can be extracted from the connected components of this new graph.

```
# all pairs (i,j) such that i < j
combinations <- unlist(sapply(seq_along(g_list), 
                              function(j) lapply(seq_len(j-1), 
                                          function(i) c(i,j))), 
                       recursive = FALSE) 
# filter the isomorphic pairs
iso <- Filter(function(pair) isomorphic(g_list[[pair[1]]],g_list[[pair[2]]]), 
              combinations) 
# convert to data frame
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(iso), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)) 
# build graph where the vertices are the components 
# and the edges indicate the isomorphic property
g_iso <- graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE) 
# identify groups that share the same property
groups <- clusters(g_iso)$membership 
# the names are the indices of g_list
g_hash <- lapply(unique(groups), 
                 function(i) as.integer(names(which(groups == i))))
```

Result:

```
> g_hash
[[1]]
[1] 2 3 5

[[2]]
[1] 1 4
```

This does not match the expected result in the question but `isomorphic(g_list[[2]],g_list[[3]])` and `isomorphic(g_list[[3]],g_list[[5]])` are `true`.

It's probably not the most straightforward way to do this but that's what came to mind.

Comment: great. Your result is actually correct, I had forgoten to update `directed = TRUE` in the `graph_from_data_frame()` function. See above.

Comment: Tks for helping out. just tried the code on the "directed" version of the graph and it fails to add "3" as the new group, although it no longer joins it with the (2,5) group.  The other problem is that you are still making too many comparisons.  All i<j , for n graphs means n(n-1)/2 comparissons, which is O(n^2). I have 40 million small graphs to compare, that will never compute.

Comment: Unless there is some n-ary version of `isomorphic` with better complexity, we're stuck with pairwise comparisons and O(n^2). You could try to filter the graphs based on easy to compute properties of isomorphic graphs in order to reduce the number of pairs. For example, equal number of vertices, of edges, of distribution of degrees. Depending on the types of graphs you have, that might make O(n^2) manageable, for instance if you have lots of singleton graphs.

Comment: Tks. I was not clear. I don't mind O(m^2)  within the `isomorphic` function (where m is the number of vertex in the two graphs being compared), because the graphs tend to be small. What I need to minimize is the number of pairwise comparisons of the 40 million graphs, being fed to  `isomorphic`.

Comment: as you said, because isomorphism is transitive, each new element (graph) needs to be compared to one element of each group. So as more and more elements get grouped, in the hash table structure, the number of comparisons remaining decreases, maybe to a manageable O(?).

Comment: I really like the idea of classifying the simpler graphs (one edge, two edges - diverging, two edges - converging) in advance and only running `isomorphic` on the more complex graphs.

Comment: Sorry for poor phrasing on my part, when I wrote O(n^2), I was referring to the same n as you, the number of graphs. Determining whether two graphs are isomorphic has no known polynomial time algorithm, although in specific cases, such as trees, it can be done in O(m). The idea of grouping the graphs was to get a more manageable O(n^2), but still O(n^2).

Comment: I agree the worst case scenario is O(n^2). However, from what I understood, your code still makes too many comparisons, by comparing all pairs of i<j, for all j. Once you find some for each j, once you find a match you can stop comparing for that j, and add to i's group. The the answer I posted bellow (not very Rish, but works).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to write a solution for my problem. It is probably not very "Rish", not very efficient, with all the loops, but I think it works. Please let me know of a better way to do this.

```
gl_hash <- list()
gl_hash[1] <- 1
j <- 1
for(i in 2:length(gl)) {
  m <- 0
  for(k in 1:j){
    if(isomorphic( gl[[ gl_hash[[k]][1]  ]], gl[[i]])) {
      gl_hash[[k]] <- c(gl_hash[[1]],i)
      m <- 1
      break
    }
  }  
  if(m==0) {
    j <- j+ 1
    gl_hash[j] <- i
  }
}
```